# XO Promotion with Keyword Trigger not rendering in page

Tags: web8, smarttarget, experience-optimization

I have SDL Web 8.1.1 with Experience Optimization 8.1.1 and on the Presentation Side DXA version 1.7.

I have created a promotion that is to be Triggered when `City Keyword Location contains "Chicago"`.

I have verified that the content to be shown has been published and will show when the Trigger is set to `Trigger Always`.

When I change the promotion to use the `City Keyword Location`, set the same ADF Claim identified by the trigger-type to contain the `taf:claim:myclaim:citykwlocation = "Chicago"`, the content is not being rendered in the page.

If I set the same trigger-type in the *trigger-types.xml* to use
`<list-of-values multiselect="false">
<value>Chicago</value> 
<value>Philadelphia</value>`

Then select the trigger Chicago in the promotion.
The content renders in the page as expected.

I need to use Keywords here since there can be multiple values in the claim being separated by a comma `Chicago, Philadelphia, New Orleans`. I need to be able to setup multiple promotions that will be displayed in the region accordingly.

What configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Keywords, it currently matches by an escaped value of the TCM URI -- not the title of the Keyword.

So your claim should have the URI of the Keyword, URL encoded, with the dashes replaced by underscores (Fredhopper doesn't allow those in identifiers). For example, if your Keyword has a URI of "tcm:5-1111-1024" - the claim value should be "tcm%3A5_1111_1024".

**Update:** I forgot that the colon is not replaced by underscores but rather handled by the URL encoding.

Comment: I have updated my claims to use the TCM URI "tcm_15_4692_1024" instead of the title. I have verified the Promo is using the same Keywords but, the page is not showing the published items for those promos.

Comment: I have identified a format of the TCM URI in the claim that works and it is as follows `tcm%3A15-4692-1024` notice the `%3A` for the `:` and `-` instead of `_`

Comment: Ah, I seem to have forgotten that little detail :) 
I updated my answer.