# keyword based Trigger type in DXA

Tags: dxa, experience-optimization, taxonomy, dxa-1.7

We have a list of keywords (Cities) tagged to content. Based on the user's geolocation, we have to show the right content using XO and DXA.

My thought was to create a custom claim processor to write the location to claimstore and use that to query for the content. I tried searching for documentation/steps around DXA + XO + keyword based triggers but couldn't find anything.

Any thoughts if I can use/customize the SmartTarget module from [here](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/release/1.7/webapp-net/ExperienceOptimization).

Comment: Where do you need help? Setting a geo-location lookup as a claim is indeed a known approach (see https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3251/46). But your point on creating a query suggests this might not need to be an XO requirement (maybe Context Expression Language would fit?). If you are using XO, others have implemented promotions triggered on Keywords: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/16337/46.

Comment: You can also implement using maxmind database on your DXA web application to identify the user city name based on user remote host IP address and then match with your keyword city list to find out right city keyword and pass the keyword TCM URI to claim value, the content trigger should be created using that city keyword trigger type.